# Frobenius theorem - mixed partials

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the system of PDEs:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & =u, \\
\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y \partial y}&= e^{-x}u^2 \\
u(0,0)&=1
\end{align*}

I want to use the Frobenius theorem to show that a solution $u(x,y)$ exists. To get the system into the correct form to be able to apply Frobenius I'm told to let $$v=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$ so that $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x \partial y}=\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)=v$$
I know that for a solution to exist we need equality of mixed partials, so after I've written the system in the correct form I need to check that. However, my issue is that in making the substitution above, have we not already assumed equality of mixed partials, and thus assumed that a solution does exist?

Answer (score 1):

The general solution of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=u\quad$ is :
$$u=e^xF(y)$$
Putting it into $\quad \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y \partial y}= e^{-x}u^2 \quad$ leads to :

$$F''=F^2 \quad\to\quad F(y)=\sqrt[3]{6}\:{\huge \wp}\left(\frac{y+c_1}{\sqrt[3]{6}}\:;\:0\:,\:c_2 \right)$$
${\huge \wp}\quad$ is the symbol for the Weierstrass elliptic function :
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassEllipticFunction.html

$$\boxed{u(x,y)=\sqrt[3]{6}\:e^x\:{\huge \wp}\left(\frac{y+c_1}{\sqrt[3]{6}}\:;\:0\:,\:c_2 \right)}$$
With condition $\quad u(0,0)=1=\sqrt[3]{6}\:{\huge \wp}\left(\frac{c_1}{\sqrt[3]{6}}\:;\:0\:,\:c_2 \right)$

So, we have one equation for two unknowns $c_1$ and $c_2$. They are two consequences :

- The given condition is not enough to determine the constants for an unique solution.
- They are an infinity of solutions (This is the answer to the question raised).

One can chose arbitrary one of the constants, say $c_2=0$ for example. Then,
 $\quad{\huge\wp} \left(X\:;\:0\:,\:0 \right)=\frac{1}{X^2}\quad\to\quad  
1=\sqrt[3]{6} \left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{6}}{c_1} \right)^2 \quad\to\quad c_1=\sqrt{6}$

$$u(x,y)=\sqrt[3]{6}\:e^x\:{\huge \wp}\left(\frac{y+\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt[3]{6}}\:;\:0\:,\:0 \right)=\frac{6\:e^x}{(y+\sqrt{6})^2}$$
This is an example of solution which satisfies the system of PDEs and the condition. Of course, they are an infinity of other solutions, as shown above.

Note : The general solution can be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals instead of the Weierstrass elliptic function.

Comment: Why use $\huge \wp$?